# Convert to dictionary a tree like structure

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a python class `Event` which has a list of children `Event` plus some extra properties.

```
class Event:
    def __init__(self):
        self.m_children = []
        self.m_start = 0
        self.m_end = np.inf
        self.m_name = None
        self.m_tId = None

    @property
    def start(self):
        return self.m_start
    
    @start.setter
    def start(self, start):
        self.m_start = start

    @property
    def end(self):
        return self.m_end
    
    @end.setter
    def end(self, end):
        self.m_end = end

    @property
    def name(self):
        return self.m_name

    @name.setter
    def name(self, name):
        self.m_name = name
    
    @property
    def thread(self):
        return self.m_tId
    
    @thread.setter
    def thread(self, tId):
        self.m_tId = tId

    @property
    def children(self):
        return self.m_children
    
    @children.setter
    def children(self, children):
        self.m_children = children
```

However, when I run `vars` on a `Event` object, I get this

```
{'m_children': [<__main__.Event at 0x7faa9549a750>,
  <__main__.Event at 0x7faa893c9e10>,
  <__main__.Event at 0x7faa893ca1d0>,
...
  <__main__.Event at 0x7faa809b6450>,
  <__main__.Event at 0x7faa809be690>,
  <__main__.Event at 0x7faa809be790>,
  ...],
 'm_start': 0,
 'm_end': inf,
 'm_name': None,
 'm_tId': 1}
```

What should I do to get the whole tree as a dictionary?

Comment: I recommend recursion

Comment: In addition to what @Code-Apprentice recommends, you might also look at implementing a `__str__` method for your class.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve what you want by overwriting the `__repr__` function. When the `str()` function is called on the dict `vars()` returns it calls the `__repr__` function of the objects it encounters. So it ends up calling all the `__repr__` functions recursively.

```py
import numpy as np


class Event:
    def __init__(self):
        self.m_children = []
        self.m_start = 0
        self.m_end = np.inf
        self.m_name = None
        self.m_tId = None

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(vars(self))


e = Event()
e.m_children.append(Event())
e.m_children.append(Event())
e.m_children[0].m_children.append(Event())
print(str(e))
```

```
{
   "m_children":[
      {
         "m_children":[
            {
               "m_children":[
                  
               ],
               "m_start":0,
               "m_end":"inf",
               "m_name":"None",
               "m_tId":"None"
            }
         ],
         "m_start":0,
         "m_end":"inf",
         "m_name":"None",
         "m_tId":"None"
      },
      {
         "m_children":[
            
         ],
         "m_start":0,
         "m_end":"inf",
         "m_name":"None",
         "m_tId":"None"
      }
   ],
   "m_start":0,
   "m_end":"inf",
   "m_name":"None",
   "m_tId":"None"
}
```

Comment: Note that `__repr__()` returns a string, not a dictionary.

Comment: Yeah valid point. I assumed having a json of it is the final goal, if it should still be a valid python dict one can use `json.loads` on the output but this won't handle the "None" and "inf" correctly so using `__repr__` is not the correct way then.

Comment: Yah, this might solve what the OP really wants (a string representation of a dictionary) rather than what they asked for (a dictionary). I just wanted to point out the difference in case it is important.